# Can I create a custom compile rule to mark a public library function as "don't use"?

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I am making a C# application and I want to be sure that developers save their `DateTime` objects in Utc time in their data model. Is it possible to add a compile rule that marks a function like `DateTime.Now` as "don't use"?

I have a couple of static analyzers available:

- StyleCop
- Roslynator

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with UWP and .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Consider using [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0) instead.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for the tip. I will take a look at it. Although my question still holds for similar checks I would like to do.

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a custom analyzer